# ¿Por qué al agregar la constraint me dice incorrect sintax near 'constraint'?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

```
create database clinica;
use clinica;

/*tablas*/
create table medico (
    codigomed int primary key not null, 
    nombremed nvarchar (10), 
    apellidomed nvarchar (11),
    telefono int, 
    especialidad nvarchar (12));

create table paciente (
    codicopa int primary key not null, 
    nombrepa nvarchar (9), 
    apellidopa nvarchar (12), 
    direccion nvarchar (25), 
    poblacion nvarchar (13),
    proovincia nvarchar (9), 
    telefonopa  int, 
    codigopost int, 
    fechanaci nvarchar (20)); 

create table ingreso (
    codigoingr int primary key not null, 
    numerohab int, 
    camapac int, 
    fechaingr nvarchar (15),
    codigomed int)

constraint fk_codigomed foreign key (codigomed) references medico (codigomed), codigopa int)
constraint fk_codigopa foreign key (codigopa) references paciente (codigopa));
```

Comment: Tal vez si le das formato a tu código, puedes encontrar los errores más fácilmente. Le di formato por ti y espero que te ayude a identificar los problemas.

Comment: Si no te cobran por letra, usa nombres completos en vez de abreviaturas en los nombres de tus columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
create database clinica;
use clinica;

create table medico (
    codigomed int primary key,
    nombremed nvarchar (10),
    apellidomed nvarchar (11),
    telefono int,
    especialidad nvarchar (12)
);

create table paciente (
    codicopa int primary key,
    nombrepa nvarchar (9),
    apellidopa nvarchar (12),
    direccion nvarchar (25),
    poblacion nvarchar (13),
    proovincia nvarchar (9),
    telefonopa int,
    codigopost int,
    fechanaci nvarchar (20)
);

create table ingreso(
    codigoingr int primary key,
    numerohab int,
    camapac int,
    fechaingr nvarchar(15),
    codigomed int,
    codigopa int,
    FOREIGN KEY(codigomed) REFERENCES medico(codigomed),
    FOREIGN KEY(codigopa) REFERENCES paciente(codicopa)
);
```

Estabas escribiendo `codigopa` en vez de `codicopa`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]